# Determine whether $w$ is in the range of the linear operator $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I determine if $w$ is in the range of the linear operator $T$?

$$T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3, T(x,y,z)=(x-y,x+y+z,x+2z)\ ;\quad w=(1,2,-1)$$
I would appreciate the help.

Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. For some basic information about writing maths at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already showed that $T$ is a linear transformation, try to find $(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ such that $$\left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            x-y=1\\
            x+y+z=2\\
            x+2z=-1
        \end{array}
    \right.$$

Comment: $\overset{\triangle}{\overline{\ddot\smile}}$

Answer (score 1):

The first and last equations allow you to write $y,z$ in terms of a formula in $x$. Substitute these expressions into the second equation and solve for $x$. Then compute $y,z$ using the initial formulae.